# How to simply this logarithmic equation?

Tags: logarithms

I have  $$f(L) = M^{L-1} / (M+1) ^L $$
and
$$ L =  \log_M ((K+B)/A)$$

I am suppose to simply this to $$f = C(K+B)^{-b}$$ with $$ b = \dfrac{\ln(M+1) }{ \ln(M)}$$ for the top I have simplified $M^{L-1}$ to $\frac{K+B}{AM}$, but I have no idea how to simplify the bottom part. Some help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Something like
$$a^{\log_a x}$$
is easy to simplify, this is what you have done for the top line.  For the bottom you need to simplify
$$a^{\log_b x}\ .$$
Try this:
$$\eqalign{a^{\log_b x}
  &=(b^{\log_b a})^{\log_b x}\cr
  &=b^{(\log_b a)(\log_b x)}\cr
  &=(b^{\log_b x})^{\log_b a}\cr
  &=x^{\log_b a}\ .\cr}$$
I think this will give you what you want.